# Editing page content, I lost the HTML editing options in SP2010

Tags: page-layout, html-editor

I have a SP2010 Foundations site and I was editing my content pages and using the HTML option to make small tweaks here or there. I've created my own Master Page and added my own CSS as well. Things were going great, then I added some more pages into the Site Pages library and now the new ones and the old ones don't have the option for HTML anymore, it's just Styles and Text Layout. The Markup ribbon toolbar option is gone. No option to edit HTML or select my HTML styles like H1, H2, etc.

How do I get it back? I don't get why/how I lost it!

Thanks,

Comment: So I dove back in by adding a Content Editor Web Part, still no Markup toolbar. I referenced a text file which contains my content, then all of a sudden it was there! I removed the content editor WP and it stayed there. I added some custom HTML and my elements, came back in and it was gone again. 

AHHHHhhhhhh...... :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most likely explanation is that your master page changes have impinged somehow on the JavaScript responsible for managing the ribbon. I would try switching back to the default v4 master page and see if the ribbon behaves itself.

Comment: I found a workaround, if I insert an image, then the markup toolbar appears! So i add it, then delete it and i can do my thing. 

I dont have much in my CSS and nothing for a site wide javascript.